# There are 3 redux form between 3 redux from only one submit button and only single api so i to put 3 of form data on single api

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Client Requirement is used 3 redux-from and used only one Submit Button and he gives me only 1 API between 3 forms.
So I need help to get all 3 forms of data and send input in a single API.

What I am used and how?

Comment: Can you please try to write your question in a different way? It's kind of difficult to understand your problem..

Comment: I have a 3 redux-form with a different name and all are in a placed on a single page. between 3 redux forms, only one submit button.
If I submit forms all redux forms value simple display on 1 alert massage.

Comment: Why have you splitted into three forms?